# How to insert and pull data out of temporary table using the one SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wondering how I can either use multiple or the same select statement to to insert data into a temporary table and then select data out of the temporary using the same query.

```
SELECT ADDRESS INTO tempTable FROM LOCATION,
SELECT AddrFMT([ADDRESS]) AS ADDRESS1 FROM  tempTable;
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: ACCESS and MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2 And Management Studio

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this process?

Comment: Why don't you select directly from the `LOCATION` for the final results ?

Comment: I need to run a query which returns the Alias and not the original column it self. When I run the query, I am getting both the Alias and the Column. This is why I was thinking about temporary table.

Comment: Could you do a select address as address1 from location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I can't speak for MS Access, but this answer will apply to SQL Server.*

Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, or you're using the word **"query"** loosely, but you can make this two statements.  You wouldn't be using the comma (`,`) that you have in your original question.  You create the temp table in your first batch and then as long as the connection has persisted you can then select off of the temp table (and use a function as it seems you are doing).

```
select address
into tempTable
from location
go

select address
from tempTable
go
```

This is valid and typical.

**EDIT**

```
select address as YourAliasName
from location
```

**EDIT 2**

```
select address_mod
from
(
    select address1, address2 as address_mod
    from location
) a
```

Comment: Doesn't work in ACCESS 2010 but you did mentioned that.
The Error is:Syntax error in FROM clause.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy I would guess that's because of the temp table creation isn't the `select ... into ... from ...` like SQL Server does.  With correct Access syntax, that should work for you.

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do, I need to run a query which returns the Alias and not the original column it self. When I run the query, I am getting both the Alias and the Column. This is why I was thinking about temporary table.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy see my edit to my post.  That is how you would alias a column with a new "name".  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for the time and effort, yes I know how to do the Alias part. However, Lets say I run a select statement in a query, I want to display only the Alias column, currently when I run a select statement, I get both the original column and the Alias column.

Example: `Select ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2 AS ADDRESS_MOD FROM LOCATION`
In the result, is it possible to see only ADDRESS_MOD

This is why I was first sending the data to a tempTable than getting only the Alias table from the tempTable.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy why are you selecting `address1` from the table to begin with??  If you just want adress2 (address_mod) from the table that would be sufficient.  You could always do something like my second edit on my post.

Answer (score 0):

2 actions == 2 statements:

1) "select into" or "insert"

2) "select from"

Answer (score 0):

you won't be able to do this in SQL Server. The INSERT will have to be on a different statement than the select.

you can do this however

```
INSERT INTO tempTable
SELECT address
FROM location

SELECT AddrFMT([ADDRESS]) AS ADDRESS1 
FROM tempTable
```

Comment: for access you will need the select into syntax that you already mentioned, you still need two separate queries, one for insert and one for select though